# juju cannot create a new machine on Azure

Tags: juju, azure

I am playing with juju on Azure and managed to deploy (juju-gui, mysql, tomcat7).
and I have also destroyed couple of services.

I should mention that I have also enabled juju high availability using the command

`juju ensure-availability`

When I tried to deploy HaProxy charm it gets stuck with saying

`agent-state-info: 'cannot get machine 9: EOF'`

I could not find this googling or in juju documentations.

Kindly what does this error msg means?
How to avoid it next time? did I make a mistake with the configurations?
How to resolve it? doing `juju resolved haproxy/0` gives me `ERROR unit "haproxy/0" is not in an error state` should I just destroy the charm? Thanks

Here is my `juju status haproxy/0` result

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Juju>juju status haproxy/0
environment: azure
machines:
  "9":
    agent-state-info: 'cannot get machine 9: EOF'
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
services:
  haproxy:
    charm: cs:trusty/haproxy-7
    exposed: false
    relations:
      peer:
      - haproxy
      reverseproxy:
      - tomcat7
    units:
      haproxy/0:
        agent-state: allocating
        machine: "9"
```

and here is the full status (It's long ;p):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Juju>juju status
environment: azure
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.3
    dns-name: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
    instance-id: juju-azure-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    instance-state: ReadyRole
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1792M root-disk=130048M
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.3
    dns-name: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
    instance-id: juju-azure-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    instance-state: ReadyRole
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1792M root-disk=130048M
  "4":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.3
    dns-name: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
    instance-id: juju-azure-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    instance-state: ReadyRole
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1792M root-disk=130048M
  "5":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.3
    dns-name: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
    instance-id: juju-azure-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    instance-state: ReadyRole
    series: precise
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1792M root-disk=130048M
  "6":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.3
    dns-name: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
    instance-id: juju-azure-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    instance-state: ReadyRole
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1792M root-disk=130048M
  "7":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.3
    dns-name: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
    instance-id: juju-azure-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    instance-state: ReadyRole
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1792M root-disk=130048M
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "8":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.3
    dns-name: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
    instance-id: juju-azure-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    instance-state: ReadyRole
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1792M root-disk=130048M
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "9":
    agent-state-info: 'cannot get machine 9: EOF'
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
services:
  haproxy:
    charm: cs:trusty/haproxy-7
    exposed: false
    relations:
      peer:
      - haproxy
      reverseproxy:
      - tomcat7
    units:
      haproxy/0:
        agent-state: allocating
        machine: "9"
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:trusty/juju-gui-27
    exposed: true
    units:
      juju-gui/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.3
        machine: "1"
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
      juju-gui/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.3
        machine: "6"
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
  mysql:
    charm: cs:trusty/mysql-25
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
      db:
      - openmrs
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.3
        machine: "4"
        public-address: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
  openmrs:
    charm: cs:precise/openmrs-1
    exposed: false
    relations:
      database:
      - mysql
      tomcat-war:
      - tomcat7
    subordinate-to:
    - tomcat7
  tomcat7:
    charm: cs:precise/tomcat7-4
    exposed: true
    relations:
      cluster:
      - tomcat7
      juju-info:
      - openmrs
      website:
      - haproxy
    units:
      tomcat7/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.3
        machine: "5"
        open-ports:
        - 8080/tcp
        public-address: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
        subordinates:
          openmrs/0:
            upgrading-from: cs:precise/openmrs-1
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.3
            public-address: juju-azure-xxx.cloudapp.net
```